# Highcharts Label Date Format

Tags: highcharts, date-format

We're currently using highcharts with date format being displayed as '**Tuesday, 18.February**'.

How can we change this format to '**Tues 18 Feb**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, Below worked seamlessly:

```
xAxis: {
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%a  %e  %b'  
         } 
       }
```

Please also refer to https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats